# Evaluating a run time expression in Struts2 tag

Tags: struts2

The following tag is faulty

```
<s:textfield  name="st_enroll.name"  value="getText('st_enroll.name')"   theme="simple" />
```

Since you cant insert expression in struts2 tags i read that by using getText you could insert expressions but that doesn't work. Any idea how i could insert the expression ${st_enroll.name} in the value field of the struts2 tag ?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"; the `value` attribute can most certainly be an expression. `%{st_enroll.name}` would try to get the `name` property from whatever `st_enroll` was. Boo hiss for not following sane Java property naming conventions, though.

Comment: cant it be a jstl expression ?

Comment: like value="${Someprop.prop}"

Comment: hope this answers your second question [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/why-cant-i-use-jstl-style-el-expressions-in-struts-tags.html)

Comment: @MistyD In tags, no (as per Ravi's link), is there a reason you won't use OGNL?

Comment: Struts2 tags allow OGNL expressions, but not EL expressions.  Some details on using OGNL can be found here:  http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html and here:  http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html.  An exception, though, to the no-EL rule is the set tag:  http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/set.html.  OGNL is more flexible and expressive than EL and really adds a lot of functionality that you will appreciate with more experience.

Comment: @DaveNewton my best option here i guess is to go with OGNL , I didnt want to alter the code of the JSPS , preserving their originality during migration to struts2 implementation.

Answer (score 2):

you should wrap the method using '**%{}**'

```
<s:textfield  name="st_enroll.name"  value="%{getText('st_enroll.name')}"   theme="simple" />
```